# Load font style of OpenType font in lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, lua, opentype

I got some problems loading `.otf` fonts with `fontspec` in `lualatex`. What I don't get is the following: Let's suppose I have several `.ttf` font styles. Then I will just specify them succesively for my main font styles.

```
\setmainfont{SourceSansPro-Light}[
    Path = fonts/, 
    BoldFont = SourceSansPro-Regular, 
    ItalicFont = SourceSansPro-LightIt]
}
```

However, I have **only one** SourceSansPro-Regular.otf file containing the bold and the italic style as well. If I specify this file exclusively, the other styles don't get loaded. So how do I include the other styles? It's probably an easy task, but I don't really understand the documentation...

**EDIT:** SourceSansPro is supposed to be an example; it could be any other font.

Comment: Why dont you `\usepackage[light]{sourcesanspro}`?

Comment: because my actual font isn't sourcesanspro. It was supposed to be an example.

Comment: @UltimateTrick The question can't really be answered without saying how the actual font is implemented. Normally a font file contains only one font, e.g. SourceSansPro-Regular.otf and SourceSansPro-It.otf are different files. So the only way I would know about how this would work would be a ttc file (basically a collection of multiple fonts, you just have to specify the index) or a Variable Font (these are mostly used for different widths and weights though and currently are not implmented in luaotfload)

Comment: Hm okay. In this specific case my font ist Myriad Pro, stored only under `MyriadPro-Regular.otf`. And in MS Word I can switch to italics or bold. Perhaps, these are just MS Word generated?!

Comment: @UltimateTrick Right, normally Myriad Pro also has separate font files for italic/bold fonts, but you might have to pay for them separatly. Otherwise Word probably uses fake bold/fake italic fonts. fontspec can do the same (look at `AutoFakeBold` `AutoFakeSlant` in the manual) but you get way better results with the real variants.

Comment: Aha! Another reason to hate MS Word :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I was just confused by MS Word's fake bold/fake italic:  An `.otf` font file contains only *one* font.